# 2010 to 2013 upgrade breaks MySite Host navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation, upgrade

So I've been testing an upgrade of our SharePoint 2010 MySite Host to SharePoint 2013. I currently have a fresh SharePoint 2013 farm set up, and I'm restoring the 2010 content database to it using PowerShell. Everything seems to work fine after I upgrade the site collection to 2013, except the following:

Whenever I make any changes to the navigation settings for the top level site, it sets up the current navigation as if I have it set to "Structural Navigation" with "Show subsites" enabled. No matter what I change it to after that (including managed metadata) it shows all my subsites in the current navigation in alphabetical order. This is a serious problem as there are about 60 subsites

Before I make any changes, the menus appear normal. It's only after I go into `/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx` and click OK that it does this. Any insight on what might be causing this? I wouldn't even know where to begin to look.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues. You might want to try using the "sort manually" feature in your top navigation.

I've got mine set up for structural navigation, showing subsites. Then again, our environment has a lot of the site collection I separate DBs, which inherently requires manual configuration of the nav bar (and filtering based on target audiences). You can also limit the number of sites displayed there, for what it's worth (I believe it defaults to 50).

Comment: In my case, sharepoint is completely ignoring both of those directives.  If I set it to "Show Subsites" with a maximum of one and sort manually, only one shows up in the sorting menu (where you can pick the order and hide sites) but the actual navigation still shows every subsite.

Comment: Which template are you using? Seattle or Oslo -- or a custom one? Do notice that, in the sorting menu, there are two tiers, not just the global-navigation one (you might have to scroll down a bit).

Comment: Yep, I'm making my changes on the "Current Navigation" tier.  I've even tried enabling subsites, and then hiding them individually in that menu, but they still show up.  This is really puzzling.  I'll have to take a look at the templates.